# Проблема с re_path в Django

Tags: python, django

Есть следующий код:

```
blog/urls.py

from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, re_path
from django.conf.urls import include

from blog.views import home, about, show_article

urlpatterns = [
    path('home', home, name='home'),
    path('about', about, name='about'),
    re_path(r'^articles/(?P<article_id>[0-9]+)/$', show_article, 
    name='article'),
]
```

---

```
blog/views.py

from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404

# Create your views here.
from blog.models import Article


def home(request):
    articles = Article.objects.all()
    context = {
    'articles' : articles
    }
    return render(request, 'blog/home.html', context)


def about(request):
    return render(request, 'blog/about.html')


def show_article(request, article_id):
    article = get_object_or_404(Article, id = article_id)
    return render(request, 'blog/article.html', {'article' : article} 
    )
```

---

```
blog/templates/blog/atricle.html

{% extends 'blog/base.html'%}

{% block title %}
    {{ article.title }}
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}

    <h1>{{ article.title }}</h1>
    <p>{{ article.text }}</p>

{% endblock %}
```

---

```
blog/templates/blog/home.html


{% extends 'blog/base.html' %}

{% block title %}
Blog
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}

    <h1>Home</h1>

    {% for article in articles %}
        <h4><a href="{% url 'article' article_id %}">{{ article.title 
        }}</a></h4>
        <p>{{  article.get_short_text }}</p>
    {% endfor %}

{% endblock %}
```

---

И код ошибки:

```
Internal Server Error: /blog/home
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/nafanya/.local/lib/python3.5/site-
packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 35, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/nafanya/.local/lib/python3.5/site-
packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 128, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/home/nafanya/.local/lib/python3.5/site-
packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 126, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, 
**callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/nafanya/PycharmProjects/Test/blog/views.py", line 13, in 
home
    return render(request, 'blog/home.html', context)
  File "/home/nafanya/.local/lib/python3.5/site-
packages/django/shortcuts.py", line 36, in render
    content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, 
using=using)
  File "/home/nafanya/.local/lib/python3.5/site-
packages/django/template/loader.py", line 62, in render_to_string
    return template.render(context, request)
  File "/home/nafanya/.local/lib/python3.5/site-
packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 61, in render
    return self.template.render(context)
  File "/home/nafanya/.local/lib/python3.5/site-
packages/django/template/base.py", line 175, in render
    return self._render(context)
  File "/home/nafanya/.local/lib/python3.5/site-
packages/django/template/base.py", line 167, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/home/nafanya/.local/lib/python3.5/site-
packages/django/template/base.py", line 943, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "/home/nafanya/.local/lib/python3.5/site-
packages/django/template/base.py", line 910, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/home/nafanya/.local/lib/python3.5/site-
packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 155, in render
    return compiled_parent._render(context)
  File "/home/nafanya/.local/lib/python3.5/site-
packages/django/template/base.py", line 167, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/home/nafanya/.local/lib/python3.5/site-
packages/django/template/base.py", line 943, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "/home/nafanya/.local/lib/python3.5/site-
packages/django/template/base.py", line 910, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/home/nafanya/.local/lib/python3.5/site-
packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 67, in render
    result = block.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/home/nafanya/.local/lib/python3.5/site-
packages/django/template/base.py", line 943, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "/home/nafanya/.local/lib/python3.5/site-
packages/django/template/base.py", line 910, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/home/nafanya/.local/lib/python3.5/site-
packages/django/template/defaulttags.py", line 211, in render
    nodelist.append(node.render_annotated(context))
  File "/home/nafanya/.local/lib/python3.5/site-
packages/django/template/base.py", line 910, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/home/nafanya/.local/lib/python3.5/site-
packages/django/template/defaulttags.py", line 447, in render
    url = reverse(view_name, args=args, kwargs=kwargs, 
current_app=current_app)
  File "/home/nafanya/.local/lib/python3.5/site-
packages/django/urls/base.py", line 88, in reverse
    return iri_to_uri(resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix, 
*args, **kwargs))
  File "/home/nafanya/.local/lib/python3.5/site-
packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 632, in _reverse_with_prefix
    raise NoReverseMatch(msg)
django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'article' with 
arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['blog\\/articles/(?
P<article_id>[0-9]+)/$']
[08/Mar/2018 16:51:24] "GET /blog/home HTTP/1.1" 500 168314
```

---

Прошу, помогите решить эту ошибку. 
Версия Django 2.0.3
Python 3.5.4rc1

Comment: Ошибка в home.html, но его к вопросу вы не приложили.

Comment: добавил home.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Откуда взялась переменная `article_id`? Подозреваю, там должно быть

```
{% for article in articles %}
    <h4><a href="{% url 'article' article.id %}">{{ article.title }}</a></h4>
    <p>{{  article.get_short_text }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```